# Simple slider with setInterval() with strange behavier

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, jquery-slider

I'm trying to make simple slider by using setinterval and jquery.
  you can have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/5m2Dq/
Slider works fine when it is in focus on browser but when we go to different tab for more than 5 min all the div's come's under each other, and start toggling.

```
$('#fbLoginSlide div:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
   $('#fbLoginSlide :eq(0)').fadeOut('slow').hide()
   .next('div.loginSlide').fadeIn('slow')
   .end().appendTo('#fbLoginSlide');
},2000);
```

Is there a simple way to achieve the sliding effect like this without any plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs probably because your browser starts missing timeouts. Especially if you are viewing another tab, the browser thinks that it is not important to call the callback with exactly 2 second intervals. You should ditch the setInterval function altogether! Use instead the completion callback of fadeOut and fadeIn to trigger the effects.

Try something like

```
var cycle = function() {
   $('#fbLoginSlide :eq(0)').fadeOut('slow').hide()
   .next('div.loginSlide').fadeIn('slow', function() { setTimeout(cycle, 1500); })
   .end().appendTo('#fbLoginSlide');
};
cycle();
```

Comment: How I can have interval in fadeout and fadeIn, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not want, use setTimeout instead if you need a timeout.

Comment: My example works better, because the fadeout is triggered only when the previous fadein has been completed.

Comment: Its nice but I'm back to the square one, because when I'm using setTimeout `setTimeout("cycle()",5000);` again same behaviour. As setInterval().

Comment: Try my example code. Also: never ever use setTimeout with a String value ("cycle()").

Comment: Thanks for this +1 - helped with a problem I had struggled with for hours.