# Timer pause automatically when I move to other screen

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a timer set on my application using html 5 and jquery. Now when I move on to different tab or I minimize my window, the timer for that few seconds stops. And again as I open the window(tab or browser page, whatever u say)the timer starts. But it gets pause for those seconds. What should be the issue ? What code should I write for it ?

Code for getting the timer is:

*Here the timer is set and it runs, but as soon as i move my focus to other page, the timer is paused. A function is just shown here.*

```
function showTime()
{
    if(ms>=100){
        ms = 0;
        s++;
    }
    // calculates seconds and hours also

    var temp= $("#clock").text(checkTime(h)+":"+checkTime(m)+":"+checkTime(s)+"."+checkTime(ms));
    timer=setTimeout('showTime()', 10);
}
```

checktime is  a function which just add a zero in front of numbers<10.

Comment: 1) show the code. 2) you cannot rely on the timer to run precisely. If you need it to, get the date when ou need to test elapsed time, rather than rely on setInterval or setTimeout only

Comment: There are many posts on StackOverflow about this. [This][1] for example.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536627/javascript-countdown-timer-that-stops-when-window-is-not-in-focus

Comment: Why not use a setInterval inestead of a recursive setTimeout?

Comment: when should i use set interval and when set time out ??

Comment: The difference between using setTimeout and setInterval in your example is that setTimout will execute 10 milliseconds AFTER successfully calling showTime where as setInterval will call it regardless. Please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve? I can tell you immediately you will not succeed in showing a smooth clock with 100s of milliseconds

Comment: @mplungjan,, I want that when I move out of my page, my code should work. But when I move out, i.e focus out, my timer pauses and when I move in, timer starts auto.

Comment: @mplungjan  can u pls guide me..

Comment: Just do a new date each time and see if elapsed tim has changed instead of using a counter

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

When you want a function to be called in fixed intervals use `setInterval`

```
 setInterval(showTime, 10);//calls showTime every 10 miliseconds
```

Comment: No, it doesnt work, the seconds move very fast and by stop code also, it doesnt stop now.

Comment: there are 1000 ms in one second. not 100

Comment: ok, but when i move on different screen, the timer stops and then resumes later