# Run function if window is not active

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing a small conversation system.

When a user writes a new message, the title of the page changes to *New Message*, which is intended.

However, if the window is active when the message is received, the title should **not** be updated.

Currently, it will display the *New Message* regardless of the window is active or not, and only removes it again when a user changes tab and back.

How do I make it only run the `if (newCount !== messagesCount)` function if the window is **not** active?

Here's the current code:

```
if (newCount !== messagesCount) {
    document.title = 'New Message - ' + title;
}

$(window).focus(function() {
    document.title = title;
});
```

Comment: Try looking here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active and here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766263/run-settimeout-only-when-tab-is-active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to track the window status listening to *onfocus* and *onblur* windows event, something like:

```
var hasFocus = true;
window.onfocus = function(){ hasFocus = true;}
window.onblur = function(){ hasFocus = false;}
```

and check in your method the value of *hasFocus*