# window focus not working in chrome when switch tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, focus

```
(function($){

    $(window).focus(function(){
        document.title = 'focused';
    });

    $(window).blur(function(){
        document.title = 'not focused';
    });

})(jQuery);
```

What it's supposed to do: if a tab is focused, the title should be 'focused'; if it's not, then title should be 'not focused'.

What it's doing in reality: after leaving a tab unfocused, its title will remain forever 'not focused'.

This is working fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome, anyone got suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: why no one answers..?

Comment: I get the impression that Chrome's interpretation of window.focus is "content focus", and not "tab focus". Have you tried clicking inside the window?

Comment: yes, it still doesn't focus

Comment: Could be a bug. It seems to work on Chrome beta/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766263/run-settimeout-only-when-tab-is-active) answer, you could easily modify that code to complete the task you've outlined here.

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact a [reported bug of Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124381) and it is happening in version 29, when you change between tabs. It seems to be a race condition that will not update the title of the tab, despite the fact that `document.title` is correctly filled.

A possible workaround for the code above is to create a timer to change the title again. 
The following code works, but you can also just set the text inside the timer function.

```
(function($){

$(window).focus(function(){
    document.title = 'focused';
});

$(window).blur(function(){
    document.title = 'not focused';

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        var temp = document.title;
        document.title = temp + "_";
        document.title = temp;
    }, 200);
});

})(jQuery);
```